# Why doesn't C code compile properly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When trying to compile some C code in Visual Studio, I often get numerous errors. The reason for this problem is Visual Studio's C compiler only supports an old version of C. How can I quickly fix all of my C code to be compatible with the Visual Studio compiler?

For example, I'm trying to compile `websocket.c` and associated headers—from http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets. I'm getting a lot of errors about "illegal use of this type as an expression" which, according to other answers, indicates that I need to move my variable declarations to the beginning of every block.

Comment: You could compile the `.c` files as C++ code. To do that, right click the file in the solution and select Properties, go to C/C++ - Advanced - Compile As. I don't know how convenient it is to set this for all files in the project at once though. EDIT: Nevermind this setting also exists for the whole project, so just do the same thing, but go to the *project* properties instead of a single file's properties.

Comment: @dialer Perhaps this is a good solution.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of following that advice blindly without understanding. If the cause really was as simple as declaring a variable too late, the error message would have been "variable declared after first instruction" or some variation thereof.

Comment: @MSalters The MSVC error message for this kind of error is indeed `illegal use of this type as an expression`, along with other confused messages such as `missing ';' before 'type'`. However, as C is not exactly a subset of C++, my solution might not work in this case, hence I posted it merely as a comment.

Comment: @dialer: I'm not arguing that `declaration after statement => error`. I'm warning that you can't invert the statement to give `error => declaration after statement`. There could be other causes, in particular C99 extensions.

Comment: @MSalters Actually I was not saying I was using the variable before it was created but rather variable declarations must be at the beginning of the current block. This is the case - if I move the variable declarations to the beginning of the block these errors go away.

Comment: @ChristianStewart: We understood. That's a C89 restriction removed 14 years ago in C99, but Microsoft is stuck on the 24 year old (!) standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The problem with compiling C in Visual Studio

Visual Studio does not provide full support for ANSI C. If you want C code to be portable enough to compile with Visual Studio, you'll probably have to target C89 or have it compile as C++ code. The first option is unnecessarily restrictive, unless for some reason you really *really* love the '89 standard C and you hate all of the new features of later standards.

### Compiling as C++

The second option, compiling as C++, can be achieved, as *dialer* mentions in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21037917#comment-31627769), by changing the target language type. You can do this by right-clicking the source file(s), and selecting **Properties**, navigate to **C/C++ -> Advanced** and changing the **Compile As** option to **Compile as C++** code.

You can also [specify the source file type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) as C++ by using the `/Tp <filename>` switch on the command line, or use the `/TP` switch to compile *everything* as C++.

### Problems with Linking

If you're linking to a library written in C, the above fix can cause linking to fail. This is because, now that you're compiling your C files as C++, the function names will be [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). When the compiler adds the library and tries to match the name of the function you called to one exported by the library, it will fail because the name exported by the library will *not* be mangled.

To combat this problem, C++ allows you to specify that specific names are exported with "C" linkage, which tells the compiler that the names are not mangled. This is usually done by prefixing the function declaration with `extern "C"`, or placing everything in a block of

```
extern "C" {
    /* header contents here */
}
```

Well-disciplined C library developers know about this problem and will use techniques, such as macros, to combat it. A common technique is to detect when the user is compiling as C++, and place macros similar to these at the beginning and end of a block of declarations in a header file:

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
#define BEGIN_EXTERN_C extern "C" {
#define END_EXTERN_C }
#else
#define BEGIN_EXTERN_C 
#define END_EXTERN_C 
#endif
```

If you're using well-established and well-coded C libraries, the headers probably contain something similar to this. If not, you might need to do it yourself (and if the library is open-source, submit the changes as a patch!)

### The future of C in Visual Studio

There is an [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) from July 2013, which announced that a large number of C99 features have been implemented for Visual Studio 2013. Part of the reason for this seems to be that the features are mentioned in parts of some C++ standards, so they would be required anyway. The new features include new `math.h` functions, new `inttypes.h` types and more. See the post for a full list.

An [earlier post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx) gives the following tidbits:

> Additionally, some C99 Core Language features will be implemented in 2013 RTM:
>
> - C99 _Bool
> - C99 compound literals
> - C99 designated initializers
> - C99 variable declarations

Note that there are features missing, including:

> - The tgmath.h header is missing. C compiler support is needed for this header.
>
>   - Note that the ctgmath header was added—this is possible because that header does not require the tgmath.h header—only the ccomplex and
>       cmath headers.
> - The uchar.h header is missing. This is from the C Unicode TR.
> - Several format specifiers in the printf family are not yet supported.
> - The snprintf and snwprintf functions are missing from stdio.h and wchar.h.

Although you can expect them in the future:

> We don't hate snprintf() (quite the contrary), we just missed it and ran out of time.

Note that other language features that don't have to do with the standard library are still not available.

It looks like standard C will receive more support in the future, although probably just because the implementation of more modern features is necessary to support C++11 and C++14.

> `<tgmath.h>` and its associated compiler magic are special and I don't know our plans for them (as Pat's post explained, C++ has overloading/templates and doesn't need C compiler magic).

Comment: Everything in this answer is right, I'm just going to leave a general note that it is really a bad idea to compile C programs as if they were C++. There are many subtle differences between the two languages: the meaning of `struct`, implicit pointer casts, the `bool` types, the meaning of `NULL`, etc. etc. Like I said, compiling as C++ is probably *still* your best option, but it's not a good one. Microsoft has really screwed C developers here. They claim there aren't enough of them to matter. Email them if you disagree.