# How to fill an array with integers and display it?

Tags: c++, arrays

I started to get really good at programming but then I reached a part in this course that I always hate: Arrays. I never completely understood arrays in C++ and it's very confusing to me. I have a very simple program and I just need a little bit of help on what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

    int num[50];
    int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            printf("Enter a number (-999 to quit)\n ");
            scanf("%i", &num[i]);
            if (num == -999) {
                printf("you chose to quit\n ");
            }
        }
        printf("The numbers you entered are %i \n", num);
        system("pause");
    }
```

My questions are:

Why isn't -999 working properly? In a previous program I just used `while (num != -999)` and it worked great but it doesn't seem to be working in this case either.
Why isn't the array printed out properly?

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you read it in - but `num` is an array.

Comment: *How to fill an array with integers?* – with [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill), [`std::iota()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) or [`std::generate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Comment: The reason it's not working properly is because you are ignoring honking warning messages from your compiler. No self-respecting C++ compiler will compile the shown code and stay absolutely quiet. Do not ignore warnings and alert messages from your compiler, even though it agreed, reluctantly, to finish compiling your code. Your compiler is always barking at you for a reason, telling you that you're doing something horribly wrong. Listen to your compiler. Your compiler is your friend. Experienced C++ developers turn on extra compiler warnings, so it barks even if it smells anything funny.

Comment: Are you compiling this code really as C++, or rather as C? No C++ compiler should accept this code.

Comment: @DanielA.White So should I change it for i instead?

Comment: No, what you should do is think about what you told your computer to do: you asked your computer to test if the address of the `num` array is whatever "-999" means for a memory address. That's obviously not what you want. Remember: a computer always does what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. Tell your computer what it should do instead of comparing the address of the `num` array with the funny memory address "-999".

Comment: @eukaryota I'm using C++

Comment: @MichealHunter Which compiler?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm using visual studio and I think the compiler is great but I'm not experienced and I don't understand the error messages from it. Can you give me a hint with code on what I need in order for the program to stop at -999?

Comment: *Why isn't -999 working properly?* Search term: break

Comment: I already gave you a hint: you need to tell your computer exactly what you want it to do, instead of comparing the memory address of the `num` array to memory address -999, which is what you told the computer to do.

Comment: -999 is not working because you stored it in num[i] and you are looking for it in num.  Should be `if (num[i] == -999) {`

Comment: In addition to what's already been suggested: Turn on warnings. Good things will come out!

Comment: Compiler error: Syntax is invalid and cannot be transformed into a program. Compiler warning: Syntax is valid and can be transformed into a program, but that program probably doesn't do what you expect. Compiler warnings are your first line of defense against logic errors. Turn them on and turn them up **LOUD!**

Comment: @MichealHunter Visual C++ 2017 does not compile it, see the error messages and warning in the bottom right-hand box: https://godbolt.org/z/gZMp_3 If you are _really_ sure that you are compiling it set to C++, I would like to know the Visual Studio version. I think both errors given by the 2017 version should have always been errors, but I don't know Visual C++ well.

Comment: I just realized your edit: Your file is named `.c`, so I am pretty sure you are compiling it as C, not C++. Are you intending to write C++ or C? Verify your compiler settings. The two languages do not work the same way although they have a lot of overlap in syntax in semantics.

Comment: *.c is a C source file, **not C++**. However even though the file name is *.c, MSVC is a C++ compiler and its C support is *very *bad. in C++ `std::array` and `std::vector` would be much easier to use. POD array is also nothing complex, just a linear storage of values, but you need to learn a small rule of array decaying to pointer

Comment: @phuclv I've never used Visual Studio. If the file is named `.c` it will still compile it as C though, right?

Comment: @eukaryota yes, but you might face many issues [Why doesn't C code compile properly in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21037917/995714), [What issues can I expect compiling C code with a C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/861517/995714)

Comment: @eukaryota With standard settings yes.

Comment: @MichealHunter Rename your file to `something.cpp` and enjoy the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (num == -999)
```

This compares the base address of `num` to the value `-999`, which is interpreted to be an address. Not the intended behavior. Check against `num[i]` not `num`.

```
printf("The numbers you entered are %i \n", num);
```

The `%i` specifier is used for a single `int`, but `num` is an array of them. Change to:

```
printf("The numbers you entered are:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (num[i] == -999)
        break;
    printf("%i\n", num[i]);
}
```

where `n` is the number of elements in `num` (which may be less than 50).

A suggestion: since this is C++ code, it's a good idea to use `cout` and C++ libraries instead of `printf` and C libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everyone has been yelling at me and saying this is C and not C++ but this is how I coded all my previous assignments and it made sense to me, I never learned "cout" in my course and I don't understand what break; is for?

Comment: @MichealHunter breaks out of the for loop and continues the code beyond it

Comment: @MichealHunter By all modern standards, that IS C code compiled with a very forgiving C++-compiler.

Comment: @MichealHunter I am sorry if it seemed like yelling. This was not intended. However everything is pointing to the fact that you are actually learning and using C, not C++. So in your own interest you should know that. It will save you lots of confusion in the future. If that was wrong and a C++ compiler actually accepted your code I would also just like to know about it out of pure interest.

Comment: @eukaryota  No need to apologize, I understand why you guys are disturbed by this but I am confused as well. This is an online class and the instructor in the videos sometimes says "in c" and sometimes he says "in c++" and that really annoyed me too since the beginning of this semester. I'm just glad I only have 3 more weeks to go to deal with all his confusion.

Comment: @MichealHunter Sounds like a terrible course then. In any case if the files are named `.c`, the identifier `std` never appears and all system header includes end in `.h` then you are probably writing C, not C++. And if your functions don't have a return type (`main()`) then you are learning very outdated C. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since you still claim (or are being told) that what you have written is C++, here an example of what it would look like in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Gimme Numbers! Just enter something thats not a number to end.\n";
    std::vector<int> numbers{ std::istream_iterator<int>{ std::cin },
                              std::istream_iterator<int>{} };

    std::cout << "\nYa << " << numbers.size() << " Numbas:\n";
    std::copy(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>{ std::cout, "\n" });
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
Gimme Numbers! Just enter something thats not a number to end.
15
45
97
8545
4654
5454
4564
54654
end

Ya 8 Numbas:
15
45
97
8545
4654
5454
4564
54654
```

---

Now the same with `person`s instead of `int`. Notice how `main()` is unchanged short of the strings for output and the type `person` instead of `int`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct person {
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, person &p)
{
    std::string name;
    if (!(is >> name) || name == ".") {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    int age;
    if (is >> age)
        p = { name, age };
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, person const &p)
{
    return os << p.name << ", age " << p.age;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Gimme names and their ages! End with \".\"\n";
    std::vector<person> persons{ std::istream_iterator<person>{ std::cin },
                                 std::istream_iterator<person>{} };

    std::cout << "\nYa " << persons.size() << " buddies:\n";
    std::copy(std::begin(persons), std::end(persons),
              std::ostream_iterator<person>{ std::cout, "\n" });
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
Gimme names and their ages! End with "."
Monica 45
Carl 35
Lydia 23
Alex 89
.

Ya 4 buddies:
Monica, age 45
Carl, age 35
Lydia, age 23
Alex, age 89
```

Comment: I'm not claiming that buddy, my online professor is. This is an online class and the instructor in the videos sometimes says "in c" and sometimes he says "in c++" and that really annoyed me too. I believe you.

Comment: @MichealHunter *I'm not claiming that buddy* – thaty why I wrote "or are being told". I just hope you see the pure beauty of C++ now compared to C ;)

Comment: To me it looks like C++ is a lot more complicated with all the "<<" and the "::"

Comment: @MichealHunter That would certainly change fast if you'd try to get the hang of it. What looks easier for reading an integer `int foo; scanf(" %d", &foo);` or `int foo; std::cin >> foo;` ?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you have to provide a break statement to exit your for loop.

You also need to read the number into a slot of the array, and then check the slot, not the entire array, to see if the new slot holds the -999

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int num[50];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        printf("Enter a number (-999 to quit)\n ");
        // Scan the input into an integer slot in your array
        scanf("%i", &num[i]);

        // Check the slot to see if you an exit condition
        if (num[i] == -999) {
            printf("you chose to quit\n ");
            break;  // you have to exit the for loop by 
            // issuing a 'break;' after you get the -999

        }
    }

    int numbers_read = i;

    // print out the array -- Loop through all of the numbers
    // using a for loop and an index, up to the number that were read in:
    printf("The numbers you entered are: \n");
    for(int j= 0; j < numbers_read; j++) {
        printf("%i \n", num[j]);

    }


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is the best way to help because now in the future I will know that I need to use a break if I had the same issue.